# Different output of matching on sequence in Scala 2.8

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

I'm a newbie to scala. I'm trying an example from the book "Programming Scala". 
The example can be get from [here](http://code.google.com/p/wing-ding/source/browse/trunk/books/Programming_Scala/src/ch03/match-list-script.scala?spec=svn33&r=33)

The output under Scala 2.8 RC6:
List: 
List: 
List:

I got the expected result under Scala 2.7.7:
List: 1 3 23 90 
List: 4 18 52 
List:

I don't know why it doesn't work on Scala 2.8. Please help me to figure it out.

Comment: I ran the code in Scala2.8 RC6 REPL and got the same result that you have mentioned for Scala 2.7.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works fine in Scala 2.8 RC6. Try to re-install it.